# The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store, apple store release version

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

i had an ios application with preexistence of sqlite database and i am using core data. 
Now i had release a new version of application with some attribute changes in core data preexistence store(sqlite). Now users update the app then app crashes on load and give the error given below. I usually fix this error in iphone simulatore but reseting the simulator. But now how to handle this problem for my real time users.

If my user delete the app and then install the new version then it works fine

[image]