# Blank xcode app generating unexpected errors

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

What I did was:

1. create new project via master detail template
2. select 'use core data'
3. build -> run using ios sim

I got the following error code:

> the model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store

I googled around and read a lot about data migration and what not. I even following the directions and tried to migrate. 
[The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store, apple store release version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185562/the-model-used-to-open-the-store-is-incompatible-with-the-one-used-to-create-the)

But then it gave me another error message:

> can't find model for source code

But since the app is not edited whatsoever, and there is only one version, why is there an issue with data migrating anyways? Shouldn't it just run with no error and just do nothing meaningful?

Comment: Yes, it should. Which app template did you use?

Comment: Sry , forgot to mention, I used master detail

Comment: Thanks. Okay, well, I just created a new Master-Detail iPhone app with Core Data checked and it works fine.

Comment: I think you need to drop back ten yards and punt, as suggested in the answer you've already gotten. See my instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the error is thrown, push the stop button on Xcode.

Then, go to the simulator (it should now be on the home screen) and delete the app.
You delete apps from the simulator the same way you do on an actual iPhone (hold down on the icon until it shakes and the 'x' appears in the corner).

Then, run the app again.

You probably, at some point, made another project with the same bundle-id. That project probably had a data-model which is different than the blank (or whatever the default data model is) in the template app, which causes your app to crash somewhere in your AppDelegate.m when it tries to load up the store.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Would you mind accepting my answer?