# i got CoreData error, what happens here?

Tags: swift, core-data

everybody!

i got learning some tutorials in swift, now in lesson there is CoreData.

So there was a project with CoreData files and i put in AppDelegate code from other project (CoreData stack)

So now i got error like this:

```
> reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one
> used to create the store
```

error shows when i try to save data  in CoreData sqlite files

PS! i was changed names in appDelegate instead they was first time in project.

How i can fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881453/the-model-used-to-open-the-store-is-incompatible-with-the-one-used-to-create-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete app from Simulator or device and re-install it.

Comment: Yes, thanx a lot! i found this but thanx for reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078337/what-to-do-when-get-the-model-used-to-open-the-store-is-incompatible-with-the-o